# How do you JOIN in SQL when you need the result of the query as a parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm currently doing a query and then running another query inside the while loop which I know is bad practice. I know I need to do a join of some sort, but I need the result of the inner query to be a part of the outer query and I'm not sure how to do it.

```
$departments = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM departments");
$departments->execute();

while ($row = $departments->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $department_id = $row['department_id'];

    $total_problems = $db->prepare("SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM `problems` WHERE department =$department_id"); 
    $total_problems->execute();
    $department_problems = $total_problems->fetchColumn(0);
}
```

I've tried various joins but am unable to get my head around it properly.

Comment: Presumably you are using MySQL.  You should tag your query with the appropriate database.

Comment: You're also using PDO wrong - your prepared statement isn't using parameterized queries.  **This** instance is safe (because presumably `department_id` is an int or very short character type, coming from the db), but other areas in your code may be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `group by` query and a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT d.department_id, count(p.department_id)
FROM departments d left outer join
     problems p
     on d.department_id = p.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id;
```

The `left outer join` is important so you get all departments, regardless of whether or not they have problems.

Comment: Thanks! This has helped me massively.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks around "problems" may be your problem.

Try instead:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM problems WHERE department = $department_id
```

EDIT:

Without the table descriptions it's going to be difficult to give you some working code, but let's try. Given two related tables:

```
departments
-----------
department_id
department_name

problems
--------
problem_id
department_id
problem_name
```

Here's how you'd join them and get only problem counts by department without any description of the problems:

```
SELECT d.department_name, COUNT(p.problem_id)
FROM departments AS d, problems AS p
WHERE p.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
```

That's using the "old style" join syntax in the where clause.

If you want to explicitly use JOIN clauses, try this (note it's untested, and your particular database might not like that join syntax):

```
SELECT d.department_name, COUNT(p.problem_id)
FROM departments AS d
INNER JOIN problems AS p ON d.department_id=p.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
```

Comment: No, he explicitly wants only 1 query, and the two queries individually don't have any (other) problems.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon already explained the importance of a `LEFT JOIN`. Aggregating the `problems` table *before* you join might be faster:

```
SELECT d.*, p.ct
FROM   departments d
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT department, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   problems
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) p ON p.department = d.department_id;
```

Returns `NULL` for `ct`, where no problems are found.
Use `COALESCE(p.ct, 0) AS ct` if you want `0` instead.

If you should *only* be interested in *departments with problems*, use an `[INNER] JOIN` to return only those rows. Faster, too.

Aside: If it's not a typo, I suggest to use `department_id` as column name in the `problems` table as well.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you run both queries to see which is faster in your setting and leave a comment here with the results?